# addClass with jQuery Isn't Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am changing the data-position of 2 rows in a table. The classes for the arrow-up and arrow-down images are not being set correctly.

If position is 1, then it should be only an arrow-down. Likewise, if position is the last, then only the arrow-up should be available. In any other case, both arrows should be visible.

Here is the JavaScript I tried:

```
function sortTable( tablename )
{
    var count = $("#" + tablename + " tr").length;
    $("#" + tablename + " tr").each(function()
    {
        var that = $(this);
        if (that.data("position") == 1)
        {
            $(this)
                .find("img.rowUp")
                .addClass("imgDisplayNone" );
        }
        else if (that.data("position") == count)
        {
            $(this)
                .find("img.rowDown")
                .addClass("imgDisplayNone" );
            console.log("positon == anzahl" + that.data("position") + " anzahl " + count);
        }
        else if(that.data("position")>1 && that.data("position")< count)
        {
            $(this)
                .find("img.rowUp")
                .removeClass("imgDisplayNone" );
        }
    });

}
```

I think the problem is the difference between the sourcecode and the DOM-manipulation, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I have read that I need jQuery's `.index`, but I don't know how to implement it.

Thank you for your help.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eVz69/4/) to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: Add your HTML markup... or make a JSfiddle and reduce this code to where you think error is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with just CSS:

```
tr:first-child img.rowUp { display: none }
tr:last-child img.rowDown { display: none }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Q8T/

Comment: Respect ! if you really understood what he means, I am struggling for 5 minutes already to just understand what is the issue and I can't understand still +1

Comment: If it answers your question, please mark it as correct.

Comment: i mark always, when the answer is correct. thanks for your help